# Import Excel add-in library into R

Tags: r, excel, vba, excel-addins

Is it possible to import an Excel add-in file into R?
I wish to use my user-defined functions contained in there in R without having to write them all up again.

If possible, which function or R library I should use?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use it with [R.Net](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=rdotnet). If you have further problems, let me know...